# Count found text on Kate

Tags: notepad++, kate

Notepad++ has this option that lets you count the number of times your search appears in a document (the button "count"). 
I'm looking for the same thing in Kate, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/kate/edit-menu.html) (Explained under `Edit`→`Replace...`):

> The **Find All** button highlights all matches in the document and shows
>   the number of found matches in a small popup.

Comment: That link is broken.

Comment: @DavidDoria Fixed. :)